# Design cell from storyboard and programmatically insert rows to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to design a cell from the storyboard and then programmatically insert rows with the custom design? For example:

[image]

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {

        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")
    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: what's the issue what do you mean by programmatically insert rows? Use numberOfRowsInSection to get required number of rows.

Comment: yes , why not , just create a cell using Storyboard and create a custom tableviewcell class and then customize it acccordingly and whenver you want to insert new row , just increase your number of rows values and simply Reload Table .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is. In fact it is common practise to do so. There are various guides and tutorials available on the topic.

In short:

1. You can design the cell in Xcode's interface builder, then assign an identifier to the cell.
2. After that create a class to manage the cell
3. Then create the cell using its identifier

It's really not that far off from what you already posted in your question.

Fur further reference, I have included a tutorial here: [Link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Happy coding !

Comment: I created the custom class and identifier, registered it with `myTableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCustomCell")` but it is still not working. I'm super new to swift as I just moved on from Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

create new UITableViewCell with xib file

```
private let customReusableIdentifier = "customCell"
private let customCellNib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(commentCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: commentReusableIdentifier)
}
```